# Unable to display nodes of the list properly starting from the tail to head

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My insert method explanation:
I assigned the "next variable" of tail to hold the address of the old node. I assigned the tail with the new node inserted into the list.

I tried to display the list starting from the tail and going through the list until it reached the head.

Problem:
But the input displayed C which is not what I wanted. Display method is supposed to display C, B, A.

I even debug my code on paper. I don't know why the display is not retrieving the last address of the nodes linked in the linked list. It only retrieved the last node in the list and display only that last node in the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.insert("A");
        list.insert("B");
        list.insert("C");
        list.display();

    }

public void insert(String data)
    {
        Link link = new Link(data);

        // this code only executes the first time when the list has 
        // no node
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = link;
            tail= link;
        }
        // this code will execute when the linked list has one or more node                                 
        else
        {
            tail.next = tail;
            tail = link;

        }
    }

    public void display()
    {

        while(tail != null)
        {
            System.out.println(tail.data);
            tail = tail.next;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Should not it be tail.next = link, tail = tail.next? The way you have it is tail.next = tail which will point to the same note and will create a loop.

Comment: I tested your code but the linked list still display "C."

Comment: in "display" are you iterating over the items in list? it looks like you are only printing tail. The first node in your linked list is head.

Comment: It does look like I am printing tail. But in the insert I have tail.next = tail which connects the nodes together. I'm having the next variable hold reference to the node before the new node is added to the list. Isn't the job of next variable of a node to contain the old node?

Comment: Does tail.next = tail link them? is this not the same object linking to itself?

Comment: The  tail.next = tail is odd to me, you want to add "link", link is the next object.  so tail.next = link

Comment: I tested your code, but the linked list still display "C".

Comment: try starting at head, do you get A,B,C ?

Comment: Yes if I start from head, I get A,B,C. Does that mean if I have two types of method for displaying the list, one method starts from the tail and other method starts from the head, I need to have two types of insert methods?

Comment: You are almost there, each node in your list knows its own tail ( its next) but it does not know the previous node. The list has a head ( first element), and a tail ( last element). A bi-directional link list requires each node to know its previous and next siblings. Check out [Doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76254/discussion-between-nicholas-and-paxic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a singly linked list. The list has a head and tail, the links are from head to tail. A singly linked list by design has one direction "forward". With elements [a,b,c] the list is linked a->b->c. To print the elements in reverse order you have at least two options. Use recursion to print the elements c , b, a or implement a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

Comment: You could change your structure to be "reversed" and have a direction of tail to head but hat would not be be advisable - it goes against the grain , the expected behaviour is head to tail.

Comment: So singly linked list must only traverse from "head to tail". But doubly linked you can traverse from "head to tail" and "tail to head".